# Need to understand where to look for the error in a javascript script

Tags: javascript, github

So I am really lost in JS world and I will appreciate all the help I can get. What I am trying to do is to use a github action to update a Pull Request comment or create one.
I have combined a lot of stuff in the following script and I can not resolve the error at the bottom. I know it is Syntax one, but belive me I am not sure how to read the error msg at all. I would love someone to point me at what line to look

```
Run actions/github-script@v6
  with:
    github-token: ***
    script: const fs = require("fs");
  const plan = fs.readFileSync("/tmp/plan.txt", {encoding: 'utf-8'});
  const maxGitHubBodyCharacters = 65536;
  
  const { data: comments } = await github.rest.issues.listComments({
    owner: context.repo.owner,
    repo: context.repo.repo,
    issue_number: context.issue.number,
  })
  
  function chunkSubstr(str, size) {
    const numChunks = Math.ceil(str.length / size)
    const chunks = new Array(numChunks)
    for (let i = 0, o = 0; i < numChunks; ++i, o += size) {
      chunks[i] = str.substr(o, size)
    }
    return chunks
  }
  
  function findBotComment(num) {
    const botComment = comments.find(comment => {
      comment.user.type === 'Bot' && comment.body.includes('Part # ' + ${num}) 
    })
    return botComment
  }
  
  // Split the Terraform plan into chunks if it's too big and can't fit into the GitHub Action
  var plans = chunkSubstr(plan, maxGitHubBodyCharacters); 
  for (let i = 0; i < plans.length; i++) {
    var botC = findBotComment(i);
    const output = `###  Part # ${i + 1}
    #### Terraform Format and Style \`success\`
    #### Terraform Initialization ⚙️\`success\`
    #### Terraform Plan \`success\`
    <details><summary>Show Plan</summary>
  
    \`\`\`\n
    ${plans[i]}
    \`\`\`
  
    </details>
    *Pusher: @pmmalinov01, Action: \`pull_request\`, Working Directory: \`\`, Workflow: \`Terraform Plan and Apply\`*`;   
  
    if (botComment) {
      github.rest.issues.updateComment({
        owner: context.repo.owner,
        repo: context.repo.repo,
        comment_id: botC.id,
        body: output
      })
    } else {
      github.rest.issues.createComment({
        issue_number: context.issue.number,
        owner: context.repo.owner,
        repo: context.repo.repo,
        body: output
      })
    }
  }
  
    debug: false
    user-agent: actions/github-script
    result-encoding: json
    retries: 0
    retry-exempt-status-codes: 400,401,403,404,422
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ***
    PLAN: terraform
  
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new AsyncFunction (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncFunction (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:13340:16)
    at main (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:13436:26)
    at Module.858 (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:13413:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:24:31)
    at startup (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:43:19)
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:49:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6/dist/index.js:52:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made syntax error in Template literal syntax. change

```
comment.user.type === 'Bot' && comment.body.includes('Part # ' + ${num})
```

to

```
comment.user.type === "Bot" && comment.body.includes(`Part # ${num}`)
```